# error creating a new solution vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution

I have a weird error when I try to create a new solution in vs2010, it started today...

I get this error no matter what kind of solution I create, and in every directory on the disk:

[image: error message]

Any idea about the reason I get this message?

I tried to search the error text on google but I only found posts about errors while converting an old solution file which wasn't helpful.
Also tried running vs2010 as administrator, but nothing works, I still get this message

EDIT:

I checked the space left on my disk (26 GB), tried other names for the solution, tried to create a text file in the folder and it works

Comment: How much free disk space do you have on your C: drive?

Comment: 26 GB left on my disk, checked that too, and it happens when I try to create a new project

Comment: Try uninstalling VS 2010 and reinstalling? Probably the most viable option rather than wasting time speculating what the error could be

Comment: Does the folder `C:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\projects` exist?  If so, can you create files under it (e.g. try saving a text file in Notepad)?

Comment: Try running VisualStudio as Administrator/Checking your Read/Write priveleges in those folders.

Comment: already tried to run it as administrator, and yes I can create files under this directory (tried the blocnote thing first actually), and it exists

Comment: start a visual studio 2010 prompt and type devenv /Safemode and try agian. If that works: unload/remove plugins until you find the culprit.

Comment: @rene Thanks a lot it did work, the weird thing though is that I didn't install new plugins... Anyway now I know where to search to solve the problem, you should make an answer of your comment so that I can vote for it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common problems is one or more plugins/addons that either fail them self or fail if loaded in combination with other plugins/addons/vsipackages.

To work out if that is true in this case do the following:

1. start a visual studio 2010 prompt
2. type devenv /Safemode
3. Check stabiity of VS2010
4. Works? unload/remove plugins until you have a stable installation
5. Doesn't work? Contact MS Support

The msdn documentation on [devenv switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)